# jquery addclass on scroll for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, sass, animate.css

I'm trying to make elements fade in when you scroll down. I want them to show up as I scroll down to that point where the div starts, I got the second banner to work but the third banner content won't fade in. Plus, even though the second banner code worked, there should be a better way to do this, something reusable perhaps. I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.second-banner-content').addClass('animated fadeInUp slow');
      $('.second-banner-img').addClass('animated fadeInUp slow');
    }
  });

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
      $('.third-banner-content').addClass('animated fadeIn slow');
    }
  });
```

https://codepen.io/yubind/pen/BOQjdB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plugin like [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) for that or you can calculate the height & try something like this

```
var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
     $(this).addClass('animated fadeInUp slow');
}
```

https://codepen.io/iamaditya7/pen/aaBBpP

Comment: I found the right plugin for my project. Thank you for the idea!